# Identify these windows/doors

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I have these old windows. I am unsure if they are even official lego.

[image: Example Photo]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LEGO logo is visible inside hollow studs on genuine parts. While it is hard to identify if pictured items are genuine LEGO parts, such elements have been produced as LEGO:

[Window 1 x 6 x 3 Panorama with Glass](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=604c01#T=C)

[image]

Window 1 x 3 x 2 could be either one of [these](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=31b*#T=A).

[Door 1 x 2 x 3 Hinge on Left](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32bc01#T=C)

[image]

Window 1 x 1 x 2 could be in two versions: [with integrated glass (single piece)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=29bc01#T=C) or [with glass that can be attached (two pieces together)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=29c01#T=C).

[image][image]

Comment: Indeed, they do have "Lego" on the inside of the hollow studs. The hollow studs, and the slightly unusual lower attachment confused me. Thank you @alex

Answer (score 1):

Without a closer inspection I can't say if yours are genuine, but LEGO has made windows that look like that. Several (most?) variants (including all of yours) can be found in e.g. [Ten Windows and Doors, White](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=214-3#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)